# How to replace &lt; and &gt; in BizTalk message?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am new to BizTalk and I need to read some values from a SQL Server table. An example of the result set I am getting is the follow:

```
<SelectResponse 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/tableName">
    <SelectResult>
        <tableName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/Tables/dbo">
            <Message> &lt;item_1&gt; item_1Value &lt;/item_1&gt;
                      &lt;item_2&gt; item_2Value &lt;/item_2&gt;
                      &lt;item_3&gt; item_3Value &lt;/item_3&gt;
                      &lt;item_n&gt; item_3Value &lt;/item_n&gt; </Message>
         </tableName>
   </SelectResult>
</SelectResponse>
```

So I get my message in BizTalk (the schema is auto-generated from SQL Adapter). What I want is the following:

```
<SelectResponse 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/tableName">
    <SelectResult>
        <tableName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/Tables/dbo">
            <Message> 
                <item_1> item_1Value </item_1>
                <item_2> item_2Value </item_2>
                <item_3> item_3Value </item_3>
                <item_n> item_3Value </item_n> 
             </Message>
         </tableName>
   </SelectResult>
</SelectResponse>
```

I have the new schema (for item_1, item_2, ...). Considering that `<Message>` can appear multiple times inside the BizTalk message, what is the easier way to get what I need and how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason you are seeing this is the item Xml content is stored within another Xml structure, Message.  Xml stored within Xml is escaped so this isn't an actual problem, it's the expected behavior.

You have several options including:

1. Use a Stored Procedure that loads and handles the item Xml *as Xml and not a string* in the result.
2. In an Orchestration, extract the item Xml, reformat to include a root element and create a new Message based on that.

The problem is how this data has been stored, not how SQL Server is returning it or how BizTalk is presenting it.